# Cannot login to Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I created a standalone Stack Overflow account based off of a Gmail address.  I currently have access on 1 computer thanks to the browser cache.  However, when I try to login to Stack Overflow from another computer it says "We could not find an account for that email address".  I have confirmed my profile has the correct email and I do get email notifications correctly from Stack Overflow.  I am not sure what I need to do to get this working.

Comment: You will probably have more chance with the support http://stackoverflow.com/contact

Answer (score -5):

Thank you for the link I was apparently looking in the wrong location.
    stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Did you mean to post this as a comment?

Comment: No i just didn't know there was a support contact feature I couldn't find it